Deleting cookies puppeteer
I want to delete cookies on a page via puppeteer but for some reason it doesn't work, here's the code:
async function deleteAllCookies(page) {
    const cookies = await page.cookies();
    
    console.log(cookies)
    // Получение текущих cookies
    const deletePromises = cookies.map(cookie => {
        return page.deleteCookie({ 
            name: cookie.name, 
            domain: cookie.domain, 
            // path: cookie.path // Указание домена и пути важно для корректного удаления
        });
    });
    await Promise.all(deletePromises); // Ожидание завершения всех операций удаления
    console.log('All cookies have been deleted');
}



await deleteAllCookies(page);

I tried a lot of options to delete cookies

When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean--some cookies are deleted, or none? Which page are you deleting cookies on? What other things did you try? Thanks for clarifying. See also How to Clear History (Clear browsing data) In Node.js Puppeteer Headless=false Chromium browser and issue #5253.

let authCookie = {
  name: "mycookie",
  value: "abc",
  httpOnly: true,
  domain: 'localhost',
  sameSite: 'lax',
}

await page.setCookie(authCookie)

let existingcookies = await page.cookies()
console.log(existingcookies)


await page.deleteCookie({name:'mycookie'})

//see here for additional options:
//https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.deletecookiesrequest


I tried, but it didn't work

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
